# Using getSystemResource to access files from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file

I want to access files from a servlet using `getSystemResource`. These files reside inside the project itself and on the hard disk. For the files inside the project I used:

```
  ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
  InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/testing.txt");
```

It works if I place the files in `build/web` folder, but when I clean and build the project all of the files are deleted. Where should I put the files?

For files outside the project, I use File object:

```
 File file = new File("c://tmp//testing.txt");
 InputStream is= new FileInputStream(file);
```

Is this a good practice?

Comment: There is no need for the double forward slashes in the path. `new File("c:/tmp/testing.txt")` is sufficient.

Comment: "ur" is a Mesopotamian city. You probably meant to say "your"? Please try to write proper English. This isn't disney.com or something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files should not be deleted, unless you created them *yourself* inside the expanded WAR while the app is still running. Then those files will indeed be deleted when you redeploy the WAR, simply because they are not included in the original WAR.

The normal practice is to store those files in a *fixed* path outside the webapp context.  You should definitely not use the tmp/temp folder for this. That folder is eligible for periodic cleanup by the underlying platform. Use for example `/var/webapp/upload`. Document it properly so that the serveradmin will create it beforehand. Make it if necessary configureable by some `web.xml` param.

Or when the environment disallows creating folders and/or writing to the disk, then your last best bet is storing those files in a SQL database.

Comment: yes I create the files manually.Actually, I don't prefer saving large files in db in the case I am working on. I'll save the file name in the database and save the file in the hard disk, since I have many kinds of files, jpg, pdf, txt and others, then use the second way to reach the resource, is this good way ?

Comment: Yes, you can do so. Storing names in DB is perfectly fine. It allows for fast searching and also the possibility to store the content type and other metadata along.