# How to upload Image at specific place or path?

Tags: java, servlets, image-upload

I am trying to upload Image but I can't.
When my application is in local disk i.e. d:\ then it works.
But when I put my application on out office server and when I am trying to upload image then it isn't working.
Before I am using following path :

`final String path = "D:\\Workspace\\B2B Solution\\WebContent\\product_images\\";`

now my application reside at :

```
\\ADMIN\keyur\Workspace\B2B Solution\WebContent\product_images
```

place i.e. on network.
So which address I have to pass in servlet I don't know.

Any help please ?

Comment: Are you using a `File` object?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - no I am using PART. `final Part filePart = request.getPart("product_image_upload");`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to create the path like this:

```
File fp = new File("\\\\ADMIN\\keyur\\Workspace\\B2B Solution\\WebContent\\product_images");
```

You need to escape all the slashes in the path.

Another option is to use the third party JCIFS API to create a connection through Samba to the network share; that also gives you control over which user is used to connect to the share which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
start your path with "..\Workspace\B2B Solution\WebContent\product_images" dont use full path
```

Answer (score -1):

In That case you need to check your path. With correct path you will not get any problem.